# How to Set Android setCustomAnimations Globally?

Tags: android, animation, global-variables, android-fragments

I have a custom animaiton that I use thru 90% of my app. I need to reduce the code redundancy:

`FT.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out, R.anim.hyperspace_in, R.anim.slide_out);`

and would like to put into some kind of global setting or variable.

Have any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have some kind of static method in a class that's in the scope of your entire application such as:

```
public class FragmentAnimator {

  public static animateOut(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out, R.anim.hyperspace_in,  R.anim.slide_out);
  }
}
```

Then just call `FragmentAnimator.animateOut(FT);` whenever you need to do that.